# Телеграм бот на питоне

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

С чего начать разработку бота для телеграма? Посоветуйте что посмотреть/почитать на эту тему. Программировать хочу на питоне, не особо понимаю как подключить бота к среде разработки и синхронизировать код с ботом.

Answer (score 3):

Для начала, установите библиотеку *pytelegrambotapi* - `pip install pytelegrambotapi`

После, зарегистрируйте бота в BotFather. Очень коротко: нужно найти бота *@BotFather*, написать ему `/start`, или `/newbot`, заполнить поля, которые он спросит (название бота и его короткое имя), и получить сообщение с токеном бота и ссылкой на документацию. *Токен нужно сохранить, желательно надёжно, так как это единственный ключ для авторизации бота и взаимодействия с ним*.

Далее, в вашей среде написания кода импортируйте модуль *telebot* - `import telebot`. И указываете *токен* - `bot = telebot.TeleBot('ваш токен')`. Можете начинать писать код.

Подробнее: [клик](https://habr.com/ru/post/448310/), [клик](https://habr.com/ru/post/442800/)

Официальная документация по *pyTelegramBotAPI*: [клик](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI)

Comment: благодарю вас !

Comment: @НадяЧелядинова Если вам помог ответ, отметьте его галочкой или поставьте голос "за", чтобы другие участники это видели

Answer (score 1):

Я вчера как раз изучал данный вопрос и начал изучать вот этот бесплатный курс по созданию бота на Python [Пишем ботов для Telegram на языке Python](https://groosha.gitbook.io/telegram-bot-lessons/)

Comment: спасибо за ответ!